# Below entered code not compiled

Tags: c++

```
template<class argument1, class argument2, class result>  
class binary_function{  
    public:  
    typedef argument1 first_argument_type;  
    typedef argument2 second_argument_type;  
    typedef result result_type;  
};  
class cmplxData : binary_function<double, double, int>{  
    public:  
            result_type operator()(first_argument_type t1,    second_argument_type t2){  
                    return (result_type)(t1+t2);  
            }  
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){  
    return 0;  
}
```

Throwing the below error

> error: reference to ‘binary_function’ is ambiguous prog18.cpp:38:34:
>   error: expected template-name before ‘<’ token      class cmplxData :
>   binary_function{
>                                     ^ prog18.cpp:38:34: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘<’ token   prog18.cpp:38:34: error: expected
>   unqualified-id before ‘<’ token

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d51c560a75013858).

Comment: This compiles fine for me with VS2015. What compiler and what flags are you using?

Comment: And where is line 38 supposed to be in your 17 lines of code? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I can reproduce only by adding `#include <iostream>` and `using namespace std;` (**never** do that): https://ideone.com/4pJSBF

Comment: Just by changing c-style cast to static_cast I was able to compile using gcc5.4 with c++14

Comment: Actually there is some other code irrelevant to this above this. So, I remove that to avoid confusion.

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky as far as I can see there is no need for any cast here

Comment: @SandyS it is ok to reduce code by removing irrelevant stuff, but in that case you need to make sure that the short version still produces the same behaviour as what you are asking for, otherwise it is just a waste of time for everybody. Read also about [mcve]

Comment: @tobi303 - current code has a cast at line 11 and gcc will fail to compile it with -Werror=old-style-cast

Comment: My compiler:

g++ (GCC) 6.1.1 20160621

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky I saw the cast, but it should work without cast (ie no `static_cast` needed)

Comment: Sorry about missing this..error: reference to ‘binary_function’ is ambiguous
This is one main culprit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class template `binary_function` generate an ambiguity because it is already defined in the std, [std::binary_function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/binary_function)

You can add an use your custom `binary_function` in another namespace, use fully qualify namespaces, or just use the `std::binary_function` definition.

Comment: OPs `binary_function` is in another namespace, the global one, while `std::binary_function` is in std namespace

Answer (score 2):

Ok, given the information in the comments you are doing two things:

1. You are including a header file somewhere that includes the definition of `std::binary_function`
2. You are also `using namespace std`

This causes ambiguity since the compiler can't distinguish between your `binary_function` and `std::binary_function` which can now also be called like `binary_function`. This is why you should not use `using namespace anywhere`!

A fix would be to rewrite the class declaration of `cmplxData` to

```
class cmplxData : ::binary_function<double, double, int>{
```

By this you are using your `::binary_function` over the `::std::binary_function` and remove the ambiguity. You are explicitly calling `binary_function` declared at the global namespace.